# Exercise on the ring $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and its quotient with an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ a ring, where operations are defined elementwise.
>
> a) Prove that the ideal $I$ generated by $x = (4,6)$ is not maximal.
>   b) Find in $A$ (if it exists) an invertible element which is not $(1,1)$.
>   c) Determine if the quotient ring $A/I$ is a domain.
>   d) In $A/I$, determine if the equivalence class $[(2,2)]$ is invertible.

**My solution**
a) It suffices to find an ideal $J$ such that $I \subsetneq J \subsetneq A$. Since $2 \mid 6$ and $3 \mid 6$, the ideal $J$ generated by $(2,3)$ contains $I$. Moreover, it's bigger than $I$ since $(2,3) \in J$ but $(2,3) \notin I$. Finally, $J$ is smaller than $A$ because $(5,5) \in A$ but $(5,5) \notin J$.

b) Let $x = (a, b) \in A$. Suppose it has an inverse in $A$ and call it $y = (a', b')$. Then
$$xy = 1 \implies (aa', bb') = (1,1)$$
If $x,y \neq (1,1)$ then the only other possibility in $\mathbb Z$ is $1$. Then the sought element is $x = (-1, -1)$, and its inverse is $y = (-1, -1)$.

c) If the simplification rule holds, then $A/I$ is a domain. Let $x = (a,b)$, $y = (a', b')$, $z = (a'', b'')$, with $x \neq (0,0)$. Then, if $xy = xz$ we have
$$(aa', bb') = (aa'',bb'') \implies aa' = aa'' \land bb' = b''$$
Since $\mathbb Z$ is a domain, in $\mathbb Z$ the simplification rule holds. So we conclude $a' = a''$ and $b' = b''$. Hence $y = z$ and $A$ is a domain.

d) As in $b)$, let $(a, b) + I$ be the inverse of $[(2,2)]$. Then
$$(2a + 2b) + I = (1,1) + I$$
or
$$(2a + 4m, 2b + 6n) = (1 + 4m', 1 + 6n')$$
with $a,b,m,n,m',n' \in \mathbb Z$. But this is impossible, since the left hand-side has even components, while the right hand-side has odd components. So $[(2,2)]$ is not invertible in $A/I$.

**Question**
I'd like to know if my solution is correct. I am somewhat dubious about c) and d), I'm not really sure if what I did is right.

Comment: This doesn't invalidate your solution, but note that for part B, we also have $(-1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Oh of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part c, you proved $A$ was a domain, but the task at hand was to prove $A/I$ is a domain. Clearly, $A/I$ is not a domain because:
$$(2,2)\cdot (2,3) \equiv (4,6) \equiv 0 \pmod{(4,6)}$$

For part d, your solution is correct, but we could also use our solution for part c here by showing that $(2,2)$ is a zero divisor, meaning that it can't be invertible.

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I proved the wrong thing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, proving $A/I$ is not a domain has the consequence $I$ is not maximal.